# Python Text Adventure Game Input Infinite Loop

Tags: python-3.x, user-input, adventure

I am a beginner learning to code python by creating a text adventure game. I am using multiple resources and no tutorials. I have created the beginning scene where it asks you for your input, or a command to do something. My commands that interact with objects (the broom and the chair) work fine. I am having issues changing scenes, checking my inventory and looking at my surroundings. When I input these commands it simply requests my input again instead of displaying the inventory list, describing my surroundings (using the function cabinFrontPorchAction) and changing my location to the cliff and displaying information about the cliffs.

Here is my entire code with the portion I am having trouble with sectioned out  with #'s

```
# text game (similar to zork)
name = 1

location = "cabinFrontPorch"

loadWeight = 0

description = {
    "chair" : "It is a wooden chair there is really nothing special about it. Probably good for pondering lifes greatest questions.",
    "broom": "It is a wooden broom with old-fasioned straw bristles. It looks like a witch would love one of these bad boys!"
}

weightList ={
    "broom": 3,

}

inventory = [
  "",
]

cabinFrontPorch = [
  "chair",
  "broom",
]

heavy = [
    "chair",
    ]

goCommand = [
  "go north",
  "go south",
  "go east",
  "go west",
  "go up",
  "go down",
  "go northwest",
  "go northeast",
  "go southeast",
  "go southwest",
]

objectCommand = [
  "get",
  "drop",
  "push",
  "pull",
  "examine",
  "use",
  "attack"
]

def addWeight(x):
  global loadWeight;
  loadWeight = loadWeight + x;

def listItem(list):
  for item in list:
    print("There is also a " + item)

def objectAction(object, location, action):
    if object in inventory or object in location:
            if action == "get":
                if object not in inventory:
                    if loadWeight <= 10:
                        if object in heavy:
                            #Create heavy list
                            print("The " + object + "is too heavy to carry")
                        else:
                            inventory.append(object)
                            location.remove(object)
                            print("Taken.")
                            x = weightList[object]
                            addWeight(x)
                            print("Your are carrying " + str(loadWeight) + "/10 units of weight.")
                    else:
                        print("You have too much stuff in your hands")
                else:
                    print("You already have that in your hand")
            elif action == "push":
                if object not in inventory:
                    if object in pushable:
                        print("This object is pushable")
                    else:
                        print ("Why are you so intent on disturbing the " + object + "? It is just a " + object + "!")
                else:
                    print("You can't push this because it is in your inventory")
            elif action == "pull":
                if object not in inventory:
                    if object in pullable:
                        print("This object is pullable")
                    else:
                        print ("Why are you so intent on disturbing the " + object + "? It is just a " + object + "!")
                else:
                    print("You can't pull this because it is in your inventory")
            elif action == "examine":
                print(description[object])
                #write description dictionary
            elif action == "use":
                print("You sit down for a while taking this time to enjoy life and ponder the deeper philosophies if the world. You realize that there is an entire world out there that is yours for the taking but you also know that you aren't going to accomplish anything just sitting in a chair all day. It is with this that you realize you just wasted time by sitting in a chair.")
            elif action == "drop":
                if object in inventory:
                    print("Dropped.")
                    location.append(object)
                    inventory.remove(object)
                else:
                    print("You can't drop something that's not already in your inventory")
            elif action == "attack":
                print("I've seen some crazy stuff but I've never seen someone attack an " + object + "!")
    else:
        print("The " + object + " is not in this area.")

def intro():
  print("Welcome to Korz!")
  print("")
  print("In this world of interactive fiction you will")
  print("find lots of treasure, monsters and puzzles to")
  print("test the limits of your human mind")
  print("You will be able to LOOK at your surroundings")
  print("EXAMINE certain objects")
  print("USE objects")
  print("ATTACK monsters")
  print("OPEN and CLOSE doors")
  print("PUSH and PULL objects")
  print("GET and DROP items")
  print("You may view your inventory at anytime")
  print("And perhaps most importantly GO places")
  print("(UP DOWN NORTH SOUTH EAST WEST)")
  print("It is now up to you to use this virtual world")
  print("To explore all of the possibilities and to have")
  print("an amazing ADVENTURE")
  name = input("What is your NAME Adventurer? \n>>>")
  print ("Allright " + name +"! You are on your own from here! Have Fun!")
  cabinFrontPorchAction()

def cabinFrontPorchAction():
  location = "cabinFrontPorch";
  print("You are standing on the porch on the north side of a log cabin")
  print("To the north of the porch is a forest with lush evergreen trees")
  print("East of the cabin is a creek that runs north to south through the woods")
  print("West of the cabin are sheer cliffs that look out over a vast blue ocean")
  listItem(cabinFrontPorch)
  while location == "cabinFrontPorch":
    requestInputCFP()
###########################################
def requestInputCFP():
    action = input(">");
    action = action.lower();
    action = action.split();
    if action in goCommand:
        if action == "go south":
            print ("The door is locked shut. To go this direction unlock the door")
        elif action == "go west":
            cliff()
    elif action == "inventory":
        if not inventory:
            print("You are empty handed")
        else:
            print(inventory)
    elif action == "look":
        cabinFrontPorchAction();
    elif len(action) > 1:
        if action[1] == "broom":
            objectAction("broom" ,cabinFrontPorch, action[0])
        elif action[1] == "chair" or action[1] == "wooden":
            objectAction("chair" , cabinFrontPorch, action[0])


def cliff():
  location = "cliff";
  print("You come up to the edge of a sheer cliff just east of a vast blue ocean.")
  print("It would be impossible to get down to the beach this way.")
  print()
########################################################
intro()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think it has to do with your `action.split()`. This command will split on spaces and returns an array: see [the documentation on split()](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.split). In essence this is what happens:

```
Python 3.6.2 (v3.6.2:5fd33b5, Jul  8 2017, 04:14:34) [MSC v.1900 32 bit (Intel)] on win32
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> action = "go north"
>>> action = action.split()
>>> print (action)
['go', 'north']
>>> "go north" == action
False
>>>
```

As you can see the array is not equal to the "go north" comman,d and thus it is not in your list of valid commands.